# How to stop appending the values on change in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

*http://jsfiddle.net/tossr6ss/*

Above is my fiddle

***Jquery***

```
$('#Company').change(function(){
        var companyid = $(this).val();      
        var PrsIDNo = $('#PrsIDNo').val();                  
        $('#PrsIDNo').val(companyid+PrsIDNo);       
});
```

What i want is im trying to get the unique number according to the dropdown but now my output is like `3215040003`,`323315040003` while changing the values changing values are appending.How can i stop that ?

***Expected Output***

*`Changing value concat 15040003`*

*`3215040003`*
*`3315040003`*
*`3115040003`*

like above output is i need how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop new values constantly being appended you need to store the original value as it was on load of the page. Using a `data` attribute is ideal for this. Then on the `change` event of the dropdown you can retrieve that value and append to it. Try this:

```js
$('#PrsIDNo').data('original-value', $('#PrsIDNo').val());

$('#Company').change(function () {
    var companyid = $(this).val();
    var PrsIDNo = $('#PrsIDNo').data('original-value');
    $('#PrsIDNo').val(companyid + PrsIDNo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="choiceSelect my_prs_sele" id="Company" readonly="readonly" name="Company">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="32">Com1</option>
    <option value="33">Com2</option>
    <option value="31" selected="selected">Com3</option>
</select>
<input class="my_prs_inp" id="PrsIDNo" name="PrsIDNo" type="text" value="15040003">
<div id="PresNo"></div>
```

Comment: still im getting the same output values are appening in front of my string how can i stop that ?  `32333215040003` i need like this  `changing value +15040003`

Comment: did u understand what i need ??

Comment: working like a charm this was exactly i need thanks Mc

Comment: Damn, I didn't know about the jQuery data function.

Comment: sorry i cant able to upvote bcz i need 15 anyway thanks @Mc yes sorry i have cleared taht thanks MC

Answer (score 0):

The problem is each time the value of PrsIDNo is set, that new value is used for subsequent calls and sets. The initial value needs to be stored so that it doesn't change.

Change the '15040003' stored in the value of PrsIDNo to be stored in the name attribute instead, like this:

```
<input class="my_prs_inp" id="PrsIDNo"  name="15040003" type="text">
```

Then, make sure the name attribute is initially used to form the PrsIDNo value:

```
$('#Company').change(function(){
        var companyid = $(this).val();      
        var PrsIDNo = $('#PrsIDNo').attr("name"); // Use name attribute instead                 
        $('#PrsIDNo').val(companyid + PrsIDNo);     
});
```

Comment: I've confirmed that this works on your fiddle, although Rory's answer is cleaner in case you wanted to use the name attribute for something else.

Comment: sorry i cant able to upvote bcz i need `15` anyway thanks @edge

Answer (score 0):

Please use code below
http://jsfiddle.net/mayankipsa/tossr6ss/2/

```js
$('#Company').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    var initial=15040003;
    var companyid = $(this).val();  
 var res= companyid+initial;
  $('#PrsIDNo').val(res);  
});
```

```html
<select class="choiceSelect my_prs_sele" id="Company" readonly="readonly" name="Company"><option value="">Choose</option><option value="32">Com1</option><option value="33">Com2</option><option value="31" selected="selected">Com3</option></select>
    
    <input class="my_prs_inp" id="PrsIDNo"  name="PrsIDNo" type="text" value="15040003">
    
 <div id="PresNo"></div>
```

Comment: We don't know if the OP is comfortable storing the initial value in the JS and not the HTML.

Comment: This is a choice...Only thing he was doing wrong is like using the changed value... which he should be take care of..

Answer (score 0):

here is what you want:

```
$('#Company').change(function(){
  var companyid = $(this).val();        
  var PrsIDNo = $('#PrsIDNo').val();                    
  $('#PresNo').text(companyid+PrsIDNo);     
}).trigger('change');
```

run it again~

Comment: I don't understand what this achieves within the scope of the OP's needs.

Comment: <div id="PresNo"></div> , this is the result container,  "Its me" did a right op, but store the value to the wrong container.  just change the container is fine.